# AKS Nginx ingress private and public loadbalancer config

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have followed the docs for an AKS internal nginx ingress while still having the public one at the same time.
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx#additional-internal-load-balancer

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/e8e793bb6270448960d53d9c3fbaa927ce8fbe4c/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L472

```yaml
controller:
  service:
    loadBalancerIP: x.x.x.x
    internal:
      enabled: true
      loadBalancerIP: y.y.y.y
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

Note that my use cases are diverse:

1. Some services need to be accessible from both the public lb ip as well as the private lb ip
2. Other services need to be accessible only by 1 ip and choose which of them it is.

Based on the docs in the `ingress-nginx` repo, this should be possible without the need for multiple ingress controllers or objects

Following the docs I was able to create an ingress controller and an internal one in the same namespace under the same Ingress Controller (IC)
[image]

But what my problem is that I do not know how to reference the load balancers in the actual ingress objects.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: some-service
  namespace: shared
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: udp
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: some-service
    app.kubernetes.io/name: some-service
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-dev
    clusterIssuerEnv: dev
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: some-service
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: shared
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - some-service.my-domain.com
      secretName: wildcard.x.my-domain-tls-some-service
  rules:
    - host: some-service.my-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: some-service
                port:
                  number: 12201
```

The `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` annotation references the ingress class but it obtains only the public loadbalancer IP. How do I reference the private one and also how do I do this to be able to have both?

Answer (score 0):

i see two options:

1. for your current setup create a new [ingress-class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-class) for example nginx-internal and point that to your 2nd IC installation. The downside is here that you would need two ingress Manifests defined per Application bcs of the new ingressClass.
2. better option IMO: use one Ingress Controller (IC) installation, create two services for the IC (default one with external IP & new one as copy of the default one but with the internal IP) that are pointing to your IC installation. Now resolve some-service.my-domain.com where needed to the internal IP (DNS config).

BTW: The [ingress class annotation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation) should ne bot used anymore, there is an own field for the ingressClass now.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Based on my current state, I have 1 IC with 2 services (internal and public) which needs to be able to be referenced in the ingress object.

I will look into the `ingressClass` but as it stands, i still don't really understand how exactly to reference the internal load balancer into the ingress object

Comment: Hi @Nick were you able to figure this out ? I am in the same boat with exact same use case .